# Can't pass hidden form value from database to PHP if-statement

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement, pdo

My database table (Related) contains 3 columns:

- related_id
- article_id
- object_id

It's a table which keeps track of relationships between articles and objects. I have stripped the code. Now it just contains the delete button (x). If someone press that button I want the user to be redirected to `if(isset($_POST['deleteRelated']))` to get a "Are you sure"-message etc. But the hidden ID isn't passed correctly. The last `related_id` in the table is **29**. When I try to echo out the hidden ID i just get **29** for every delete button (x).

The complete version of the code below gives me a table with the article title, object title and the delete button (x). Because of a submit button can't pass a value by itself I need a hidden value. But when I pass it by pressing the delete button (x) i just gets **29** every time.

**Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteRelated'])) {

    echo $_POST['hidden-id']; // Will just display the last 'related_id' value.

else {

    echo '
    <form method="post">';

    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Related");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($result as $related) {

        echo '
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden-id" value="' . $related['related_id'] . '">
        <input type="submit" name="deleteRelated" value="x">';

    }

    echo '
    </form>';

}
```

If I type:

`<input type="submit" name="deleteRelated" value="' . $related['related_id'] . '">`

It will display the correct value from the database instead of the **x** for the delete/submit button. But when I press the delete/submit button I just get the last `related_id` which is **29**.

Can someone solve this problem? Should not be that hard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

You have one `<form>` for the entire table, which includes (say) a dozen `<input type="hidden" name="hidden-id" value="...">`s.

Those values will ALL be sent to the server when the form is submitted (how do you expect it to know to only send the `hidden-id` which is next to the specific `submit` button that was pressed?) This is why you are only seeing the **last** `hidden-id` – they are all being sent, so the final one overrides/wins.

### Solution

One solution would be to have a `<form>` per row instead of one `<form>` for the whole table:

```
foreach ($result as $related) {

    echo '<form method="POST" action="...">';

    echo '
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden-id" value="' . $related['related_id'] . '">
    <input type="submit" name="deleteRelated" value="x">';

    echo '</form>';

}
```

That way, **only** the `hidden-id` value of the pressed button would be sent.

Comment: I just have one hidden value at the whole page. But it's working to put the <form> inside the loop. Thank you very much mate. :)

Comment: @Treps Surely you have several hidden values on the page – one in each iteration of the loop = one in each row!

Comment: Aha, smart. I didn't tought about that.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you really don't need a form for each row, you could use a button here instead and ditching those hidden inputs.

Example:

```
foreach ($result as $related) {
    echo '<button type="submit" name="deleteRelated" value="' . $related['related_id'] . '">Delete</button>';
}
```

So now each value of that pressed button on each row will go to:

```
$related_id = $_POST['deleteRelated'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to put the  in the foreach.
In your code, you have one form with a lot of button submit.
Try this:

```
foreach ($result as $related) {

echo '
<form method="POST" action="...">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden-id" value="' . $related['related_id'] . '">
<input type="submit" name="deleteRelated" value="x">
</form>';}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right, why do you need multiple hidden inputs?
you might want to put this input once:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidden-id" value="" />
```

Next, change the submit button to something like this:

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="deleteRelated" value="x" onclick="setValue('" . $related['related_id'] . "'); />';
```

And use a js function:

```
setValue(val) {
    document.getElementsByName("hidden-id")[0].value = val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution: Put your `form` tag inside `foreach` loop

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Related");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $related) 
{
    echo '<form method="post">';

    echo '
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden-id" value="' . $related['related_id'] . '">
        <input type="submit" name="deleteRelated" value="x">';

    echo '</form>';
}
```